# function of 'build/intermediates/pre-dexed' floder

Tags: android, dex

I want to know what's the function of the floder 'build/intermediates/pre-dexed'
and files in this floder is shown as *`eventbus-2.4.0-c730f263d42e2a79f1620ebab7abdc09655820f2`* , how the value "c730f....20f2" is generated ,I guess it's a SHA1 Value.
morevover,why some object generate the floder 'pre-dexed ' while others not.

Answer (score 0):

The pre-dex folder is a cache of your project dependencies classes in dex format, to speed up subsequent builds when the dependencies don't change. Otherwise, every time you build the app it would have to convert all dependencies into dex format again, which is inefficient.

The hex string is a hash to try to prevent name collisions when multiple jars have the same name (a lot of dependencies will have just a `classes.jar` for instance).

Comment: Thank you for your answer , i found the hex string can be found in `<item .... item/> ` in file   ` build /intermediates/dex-cache/cache.xml` , however when i add another jar in the project ,the old jar-info in `cache.xml` file will be clean and only the information about the new added jar is shown in `cache.xml`, do you know how to get the odler cache info when a new jar is  added

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure about that sorry.